# mywebsite.com/HOME redirect is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I used to host my website on shared host servers, now just got a VPS server so starting from scratch and the issue here might be because there is some misconfiguration. Apache and PHP 7 are up and running fine.

I've created a simple php file to show php info and that worked fine as well.

I've also added the configuration below into httpd.conf so that the index will be the main page to be loaded:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
DirectoryIndex index.php
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

My index.php page has the code below which should basically redirect to /views/home.phtml and show mywebsite.com/home on the location bar.

```
header("Location: home/");
```

Currently, a blank page is being shown, also when I try to access mywebsite.com/views it lists all files in there (index of /views), I have /htaccess set up (Options -Indexes) to avoid it. When I try accessing mywebsite.com/views/home.phtml it shows the code instead of showing the page.

Any idea on how to get this fixed?

Comment: If you're trying to use `.htaccess`-files, you need to set `AllowOverride` to `All`. Then you should change `Indexes` to `-Indexes` (and add a `+` before the other Options-values). Also, have you configured the web server to treat `.phtml`-files as PHP-files?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
header('Location: mywebsite.com/home');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22623559)